# Spring Batch - How to use JSON/CSV String object instead of Files on disk

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, db2, spring-batch

I am building an Spring Batch application that loads fetches data from external API and loading it to Database. I am making a REST call to external API which API return JSON/CSV string based on request parameters(json/csv).

The application currently works fine for CSV file saved in filesystem. I am trying to get rid of creating a new file and using the file as input every time. I would want to achieve the loading without having to create any file on the disk.

I have googled and tried different solutions, I have replaced FlatFileItemReader with JsonItemReader.

Can you please help me here.

**ReportService.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ReportService {

    public static final String OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT = "csv";

    @Autowired
    ProxyRestClient proxyRestClient;

    @Autowired
    FileOperations fileWriter;

    @Autowired

    CommonUtility commonUtil;

    @Autowired
    ReportMapping reportMapping;

    @Autowired
    ReportConfig reportConfig;

    @Autowired
    JobMapping jobMap;

    @Autowired
    DataIntegrationResponseBuilder responseBuilder;

    @Autowired
    ImportJobLauncher batchJob;

    @Autowired
    WFitsPricingParser wFitsPricingParser;

    public ResponseEntity<DataIntegrationResponse> getReport(String jobName) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, String> fitsParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        fitsParamMap = getFitsParameters(jobName);

        ResponseEntity<String> response;

        final String filePath = Path.of("").toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\";

        final String baseUrl = reportConfig.getBaseURL();

        String reportURL = baseUrl + fitsParamMap.get("reportId") + "?format=" + OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT;

        String reportName = fitsParamMap.get("reportName");

        log.info("Fetching report from FITS API.");
        log.info("FITS API URL: " + reportURL + ".");

        response = proxyRestClient.callFitsApi(reportURL, commonUtil.encodedCredentials());

        /*
        * ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); WFitsVendor[] jsonObj =
        * mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), WFitsVendor[].class);
        */

        if (response != null) {
            if (response.getStatusCodeValue() == 200 && response.hasBody()) {
                fileWriter.writeToFile(response.getBody(), filePath + reportName + "." + OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT);

                if (jobName.equals("vendor")) {
                    BatchJobResponse batchJobResponse = batchJob.importFitsVendor(filePath + reportName + "." + OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT, response.getBody());

                    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBuilder.buildResponse(response.getStatusCode(),
                            reportName + "." + OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT, batchJobResponse.getJobName(), batchJobResponse.getJobStatus(), batchJobResponse.getJobId()),
                        HttpStatus.CREATED);
                }
            }

        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBuilder.buildResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "", "", "", 0 L),
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getFitsParameters(String jobName) {
        HashMap<String, String> fitsParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        fitsParamMap.put("reportName", reportMapping.getMappings().getOrDefault(jobMap.getMappings().get(jobName), ""));
        fitsParamMap.put("reportId", jobMap.getMappings().getOrDefault(jobName, ""));
        return fitsParamMap;
    }
}
```

**ProxyRestClient.java**

```
@Service
public class ProxyRestClient {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("externalRestTemplate")

  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public ResponseEntity<String> callFitsApi(
      String reportURL, String encodedCredentials)
      throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
   
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
    ResponseEntity<String> responseWfits = null;

    // response = restTemplate.exchange(reportURL, HttpMethod.GET, request,
    // String.class);

     responseWfits = restTemplate.exchange(https://fitsonline.trgrp.com/msmdsqa/api/report/user/5010296?format=json, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

     return responseWfits;
  }
}
```

**VendorJob.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VendorJob {

    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private static final String DROP_SCRIPT = "TRUNCATE TABLE MDIA.WFITS_VENDOR";

    @Autowired
    private HikariDataSource dataSource;

    /*
     * This is for CSV File
     *
     * @Bean
     * @StepScope
 public FlatFileItemReader<WFitsVendor>

     * VendorReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath,
      @Value("#{jobParameters['jsonObj']}") String jsonObj) {
     
     FlatFileItemReader<WFitsVendor> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

     itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
     itemReader.setName("csvReader"); itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
     itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
     itemReader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new ReaderPolicy());
     return itemReader; }
     */

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JsonItemReader<WFitsVendor> jsonItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['jsonObj']}") String jsonObj) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure the objectMapper as required
        JacksonJsonObjectReader<WFitsVendor> jsonObjectReader =
            new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(WFitsVendor.class);
        jsonObjectReader.setMapper(objectMapper);

        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<WFitsVendor>()
            .jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
            .resource(new ByteArrayResource(jsonObj.getBytes()))
            .name("jsonItemReader")
            .build();
    }

    private LineMapper<WFitsVendor> lineMapper() {

        WFitsVendorLineMapper<WFitsVendor> lineMapper = new WFitsVendorLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setNames("VENDORNAME", "Type", "Notes");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(0, 1, 2);
        
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<WFitsVendor> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(WFitsVendor.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return lineMapper;

    }

    @Bean
    public VendorProcessor VendorProcessor() {
        return new VendorProcessor();

    }

    @Bean   
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<WFitsVendor> VendorWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<WFitsVendor> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql(
            "INSERT INTO MDIA.WFITS_VENDOR(VENDOR, VENDOR_INFO, VENDOR_TYPE, CREATED_BY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<WFitsVendor> valueSetter = new WFitsVendorPreparedStatementSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(valueSetter);

        return databaseItemWriter;

    }

    @Bean
    public Step loadVendorTable() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("load-wfitsvendor-table").<WFitsVendor, WFitsVendor> chunk(10000)
            .reader(jsonItemReader(null, null)).writer(VendorWriter()).processor(VendorProcessor()).faultTolerant()
            .taskExecutor(VendortaskExecutor()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step truncateVendorTable() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("truncate-wfitsvendor-table").tasklet(truncateTableTasklet()).build();
    }

    public Tasklet truncateTableTasklet() {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).execute(DROP_SCRIPT);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("VendorJob")
    public Job runVendorJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("VendorJob").listener(new JobCompletionListener()).start(truncateVendorTable())
            .next(loadVendorTable()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor VendortaskExecutor() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
}
}
}
```

**VendorLineMapper.java**

```
public class VendorLineMapper<T> implements LineMapper<WFitsVendor> , InitializingBean {

    private LineTokenizer tokenizer;

    private FieldSetMapper<WFitsVendor> fieldSetMapper;

    @Override

    public WFitsVendor mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        WFitsVendor vr = fieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(tokenizer.tokenize(line));
        //System.out.println(line);
        vr.setLineNo(lineNumber);
        return vr;
    }

    public void setLineTokenizer(LineTokenizer tokenizer) {
        this.tokenizer = tokenizer;
    }

    public void setFieldSetMapper(FieldSetMapper<WFitsVendor> fieldSetMapper) {
        this.fieldSetMapper = fieldSetMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(tokenizer, "The LineTokenizer must be set");
        Assert.notNull(fieldSetMapper, "The FieldSetMapper must be set");

    }

}
```

**ReaderPolicy.java**

```
public class ReaderPolicy extends DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy {

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfRecord(final String line) {
        return line.trim().length() != 0 && super.isEndOfRecord(line);
    }

    @Override
    public String postProcess(final String record) {

        if (record == null || record.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.postProcess(record);

    }
```

**JSON Returned from API:**
[image]

Comment: You have to implement a custom ItemReader. An [example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-rest-api/). If the response is too big I think you can implement also a pagination logic If the external API permits it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `URLResource` and point your JSON item reader to it, something like:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public InputStream urlResource() throws IOException {
   URL url = new URL("https://path.to.your.resource");
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("", ""); // set auth headers if necessary
   return urlConnection.getInputStream();
}

@Bean
public JsonItemReader<Pojo> itemReader() throws IOException {
   return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Pojo>()
                .name("restReader")
                .resource(new InputStreamResource(urlResource()))
                .strict(true)
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Pojo.class))
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution. I will try this solution and mark as accepted answer. I would want to know one more thing, can I pass 'CSV String' that I receive from external API to FlatFileReader instead of filepath or do I have to adopt different approach altogether? The external API can return data in both CSV or JSON format. The response.getBody() gives me the string in CSV/JSON format. Currently I am writing this 'CSV String' to a file and passing that file as parameter to FlatFileItemReader. Can this be done with minimal changes without having to re-write line mappers, reader policy etc.

Comment: Your reader's definition should depend on the return type of the response from your endpoint (csv or json). So you need to make your reader definition dynamic (ie should return a `FlatFileItemReader` or `JsonItemReader`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am accepting your answer as it helped me a lot in finding the solution. God bless you.